# How to intercept and apply effects to Firefox audio/sound output

Tags: audio, effects, firefox-addon, intercept

I want to build a Firefox extension that will allow me to directly manipulate the audio output, applying live filters and effects, from (for example) a streaming video site. Im struggling to find any good resources to help me. I think the effects bit will be ok but I need to find a way of intercepting the audio stream output. Does anyone know if this is possible?

Thanks,

Tom

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, it's not possible. I don't know of any web browsers that expose an interface that lets you manipulate audio output.

Keep in mind that a lot of audio output comes from plug-ins like Flash, and those plug-ins are sending the audio output directly to your operating system - they're not even routing it through your web browser. So it wouldn't be possible for your web browser to intercept the sound if it wanted to.

Comment: Thanks dmazzoni, I had started to suspect the same. I think I will have to start looking into the Windows DirectShow filters and intercept further down the chain.